intl-tel-input library is always giving me invalid number error
I'm using intl-tel-input library. I found this library by chance, and since I liked it from the beginning I tried to use it.
Here you can find the documentation: Documentation
As you can see from the code mentioned below, if you try to insert the number (for example an Italian number, 3250001100) I get the following message:
Invalid number. Please try again.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@24.7.0/build/css/intlTelInput.css">

    <title>IntlTelInput</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="message"></p>

    <form id="form">
        <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
        <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@24.7.0/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const input = document.querySelector("#phone");
        const form = document.querySelector("#form");
        const message = document.querySelector("#message");

        const iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
            initialCountry: "it",
            loadUtilsOnInit: "/intl-tel-input/js/utils.js?1730730622316" // just for formatting/placeholders etc
        });

        form.onsubmit = () => {
            if (!iti.isValidNumber()) {
                message.innerHTML = "Invalid number. Please try again.";
                return false;
            }
        };

        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const fullPhone = urlParams.get('full_phone')
        if (fullPhone) {
            message.innerHTML = `Submitted hidden input value: ${fullPhone}`;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>



Can someone tell me why I always get the error?
Thanks to everyone in advance, beautiful people!

try using loadUtilsOnInit: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@24.7.0/build/js/utils.js" as documented in the documentation for intl-tel-input - you'll find it works just fine then - what you've done is used CDN example for the loading the main script, then used the non-CDN examples to load the utils

@Bravo Perfect, thank you so much.
